# How to Smooth corner for image in android [Algorithm not using Path ...etc]

Tags: java, android, algorithm, rounded-corners, smoothing

I'm asking about how do apply Xiaolin algorithm to have a smooth corner for image in android
I've wrote a algorithm that iterate over the pixels and determine wither this pixel should removed or not to have an corner for image also removing pixel by making it transparent 255 for alpha value but the corner isn't smooth and I'm reading about Xiaolin algorithm for smooth line but because I'm in intermediate java programmer I don't know how to apply this algorithm >>> can any one help me on how to apply this algorithm or suggest another algorithm and how to use it
 this is my code

```
int radius = Integer.parseInt(((EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editTextRadius)).getText().toString());
    int xCenter ;
    int yCenter;
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.h); 
    Bitmap drawaBitmap = mutableBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);


    for (int i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
        xCenter = radius;
        yCenter = radius;
        for (int j = 0; j < radius; j++) {
            if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

                    drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            }

        }
        xCenter = radius;
        yCenter =  drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius;
        for (int j = drawaBitmap.getHeight()-1; j > drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius; j--) {
            if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

                    drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = drawaBitmap.getWidth()-1; i > drawaBitmap.getWidth()-radius; i--) {
        xCenter = drawaBitmap.getWidth() - radius;
        yCenter =  radius;
        for (int j = 0; j < radius; j++) {
            if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2)) {

                    drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            }

        }
        xCenter = drawaBitmap.getWidth()-radius;
        yCenter =  drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius;
        for (int j = drawaBitmap.getHeight()-1; j > drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius; j--) {
            if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

                    drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            }

        }
    }
    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageBitmap(drawaBitmap);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `by making it transparent 255 for alpha value`: 255 would make the pixel opaque, not transparent. Use 0 instead.

Comment: when I'm using 0 for alpha I've got a black pixel whatever the algorithm work nice but not smooth corner this is the problem >>>> thanks @user2558882 for this information

Comment: also 255 is transparent 0 is opaque try it :)

Comment: `also 255 is transparent 0 is opaque try it :)` Not true: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAlpha(int))

Comment: Try adding `((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image)).setBackground(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));` before `((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageBitmap(drawaBitmap);`.

Comment: @user2558882 but with 0 value I've got a black pixel with 255 the pixel got transparent and disappear either I've wrote the code above or not

Comment: Let me explain this to you: `Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)`: The first argument: alpha is 255 or `FF`, second argument: Red is 255 or `FF`, third argument: Green is 255 or `FF`, fourth argument: Blue is 255 or `FF`. This translates to: `0x FF FF FF FF` ==> which is opaque `white`. I think what you are calling `transparent` is actually `white` pixels. Try setting the background of the layout to black. You will see what I mean. Did you try doing what I suggested in my previous comment? Try it with `Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));`.

Comment: @user2558882 yah I've do what you wont and I've change the backGround to black but I didn't get a white pixel I've got transpaernt pixel that dissapper :) >>>> please be sure we work on Bitmap not Drawable

Comment: `please be sure we work on Bitmap not Drawable `: So, I tested your code with my suggestions and it works. Posted an answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So, I gave your code a try and its working fine for me. I did add the changes I suggested to you. Here's the xml for ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layerType="hardware"/>
```

The reason why you are seeing black instead of transparent pixels could be because the layerType is not set. Corrected code:

```
// hardcoded this value for testing purposes
int radius = 120;
int xCenter;
int yCenter;
Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                  this.getResources(), R.drawable.h); 

// ARGB_8888 // ARGB_4444 has been deprecated
Bitmap drawaBitmap = mutableBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

for (int i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
    xCenter = radius;
    yCenter = radius;

    for (int j = 0; j < radius; j++) {
    if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

            drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

    }

    xCenter = radius;
    yCenter =  drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius;

    for (int j = drawaBitmap.getHeight()-1; j > drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius; j--) {

        if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

            drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

    }
}
for (int i = drawaBitmap.getWidth()-1; i > drawaBitmap.getWidth()-radius; i--) {
    xCenter = drawaBitmap.getWidth() - radius;
    yCenter =  radius;

    for (int j = 0; j < radius; j++) {
        if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2)) {

        drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

}

xCenter = drawaBitmap.getWidth()-radius;
yCenter =  drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius;

for (int j = drawaBitmap.getHeight()-1; j > drawaBitmap.getHeight()-radius; j--) {
    if (Math.pow(i - xCenter , 2) + Math.pow(j - yCenter , 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2) ) {

        drawaBitmap.setPixel(i, j,
                            Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));


    }

}

}

((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)).
    setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(drawaBitmap);
```

By the way, you can also use `Color.TRANSPARENT` in place of `Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Result: Original & Processed

[image]

Comment: `<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layerType="hardware"/>`
I didn't use this but I've changed the ARGB_8888 // ARGB_4444 
and `setPixel(i,j,Color.TRANSPARENT);` 
it works fine for transparent
But still this is not my problem my problem is to have smooth corner but this answer is nice that show me new information...
Thanks

Comment: @BlackRoot I think the smoothness of corners will come with a higher radius value. When I used `120` for the radius, the corners were quite smooth. What is your criteria for smooth corners?

Comment: no smoothness doesn't depend on radius >>> there is away for creating smooth corner by putting half transparent pixel with same color beside last one or something like this.
I'm read the Xiaolin's algorithm and Bresenham's algorithm but I don't have an enough experience to apply any one of these algorithm..
can you help me .... these links for the algorithm 
[Xiaolin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm)
[Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: @BlackRoot I'll take a look. I have added an image to my answer for reference.

Comment: I see this image but look carefully it not smooth see smooth [HERE](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)

Comment: @pskink not pixel one by one but putting pixel or 2 beside the last pixel :: let me explain : we make a loop inside it there is an `if` close when the clause comse false nothing happens but before the `IF` close comes false we put an pixel half transparent.,, also I'm wont to improve this code but after make smooth corner

Comment: if you want smooth alpha values then create a temp mask Bitmap with size radius x radius, draw a circle 0, 0, radius and use its alpha value when putting original bitmap pixels

Comment: @pskink can you explain more and provide with a simple code I'm near from your solution

Answer (score 0):

this is a bas stuff to start with:

```
int radius = 10;
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(2 * radius, 2 * radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
Canvas c;

// create mask
p.setColor(0xff000000);
c = new Canvas(mask);
c.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, p);

// draw something on the original bitmap
// skip it if you have original bitmap drawn
c = new Canvas(b);
LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, radius, radius, 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, TileMode.CLAMP);
p.setShader(lg);
c.drawRect(0, 0, radius, radius, p);
// end of skip

for (int x = 0; x < radius; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < radius; y++) {
        int maskPixel = mask.getPixel(x, y);
        if ((maskPixel & 0xff000000) != 0xff000000) {
            int bPixel = b.getPixel(x, y);
            bPixel &= 0xffffff;
            bPixel |= (maskPixel & 0xff000000);
            b.setPixel(x, y, bPixel);
        }
    }
}

try {
    OutputStream stream;
    stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/image.png");
    b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mask.png");
    mask.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much and I'm sorry for this late but really I need an algorithm modify the pixels -pixel by pixel- and this algorithm written in java or costumed for android. :)

Comment: to be specific the algorithm modify the original pixels not create a mask like you do thanks.